# Context menu id not coming in xsltlistviewwebpart?

Tags: sharepoint-server, xslt-list-view-web-part, context-menu

I had created a SharePoint list with two different views with a groupby query and two different custom list view WebParts with these two views.

In one of the WebPart the context menu is available but it is not appearing in other WebPart. How can I display context menu with these two WebPart in same site page.

In the image two different WebPart can be seen: `CounterPartyGroup` and `CounterParty`. But context menu is available only in `CounterPartyGroup` WebPart.

Answer (score 0):

In the View Settings of your web part grouping the items of "CounterParty", confirm that the column showing the values "George" and "Robert" (I assume this would be `Title`) is `Title (linked to item with edit menu)`, **not** `Title (linked to item)` nor plain `Title`.

---

**Update**: Based on the discussion in the comments, I'm strongly suspecting this is a **bug** in SharePoint.

I've had a slightly similar issue with using Grouped By view ([here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/164223/picture-library-with-a-group-by-view-makes-items-unclickable)), and despite reporting it to Microsoft, it hasn't been fixed ever since. The view is generally unstable, and the might be a little to do.

I'm not aware of a fix for problems with Grouped By view, but I also haven't made attempts for a long time. A suggestible step would be to report this issue to Microsoft and hope to get an answer. By using TechNet forums you may or may not get an answer from a Microsoft's employee, and you might also want to try to contact their support directly. Another suggestion, a bit out of the box, would be to try to add your web parts to different web part zones (you might need to change the page's layout to do so). Alternatively you could try to place the web parts horizontally aligned (so side-by-side, as the default layout works vertically). It would be doable as detailed in here: [Answer to How to have two web parts side by side in same zone](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/53969/21441).

Comment: yes george and robert is title field .i was added two images both views are linked to title only.

Comment: @elina thanks for detailing more. If possible, please try to add these two web parts on another page with the same implementation, but by adding "CounterParty" above "CounterPartyGroup" this time (so in opposite order). I'm asking this, because I have previously faced a different but slightly similarly occurring **bug** with SharePoint's grouped view, where the grouping's functionality worked with one but not with the other.

Comment: ya i tries that if i add counterparty above context menu working for only counterparty. for counterparty group context menu is not working.

Comment: @elina so in other words - the web part appearing as a second (below the other one) doesn't have its context menu working?

Comment: yes for that what should i do ? i want context menu for both webpart

Comment: @elina I have updated my answer.